# Armazernar valor e quantidade array PHP

Tags: php, array

Preciso varrer o primeiro `array` e armazenar o valor e a quantidade desse valor em outro `array`. Não estou conseguindo pois estou com dificuldade na hora de armazenar os valores em outro `array`.

**Array**:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "12"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "13"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "100"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "12"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "13"
  }
}
```

**Array** com o valor e quantidade que preciso:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "12"
    int() "2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "13"
    int() "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "100"
    int() "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Você quer contar a quantidade de itens no array? O `count()` não traz resultado?

Comment: Traz sim só não consigo armazenar em outro array, gostaria de um novo array que nem citado acima. Não somente um `count` mostrando a quantidade de itens do array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oi, Kevin

Acredito que você pode resolver essa questão utilizando a função `array_count_values()`. [Documentação aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-count-values.php).

Ao fim do uso dessa função, seus valores se tornarão chaves do outro array. Com um `foreach ($array as $valor => $ocorrencias)` você consegue percorrer o array produzido e colocá-lo no formato desejado. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Para complementar a resposta do Macário Martins, primeiro teria que transformar a array multidimensional em uma array simples... [Usei o exemplo do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611313/turning-multidimensional-array-into-one-dimensional-array)

```
$dados_unidimensional = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $dados_bidimensional);
```

isso vai transformar sua array

```
[ [ "12" ], [ "13" ], [ "100" ], [ "12" ], [ "13" ] ]
```

em

```
[ "12", "13", "100", "12", "13" ]
```

Com isso você consegue usar o [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

```
$resultado = array_count_values($dados_unidimensional);
```

E $resultado será algo do tipo

```
["12" => 2, "13" => 2, "100" => 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu `array` parece ser um **multi-dimensional**. Tente dessa forma:

```
<?php

$ar1[] = array("red","green","yellow","blue");
$ar1[] = array("green","yellow","brown","red","white","yellow");
$ar1[] = array("red","green","brown","blue","black","yellow");

$res = array_icount_values ($ar1);
print_r($res);

function array_icount_values($arr,$lower=true) {
     $arr2=array();
     if(!is_array($arr['0'])){$arr=array($arr);}
     foreach($arr as $k=> $v){
      foreach($v as $v2){
      if($lower==true) {$v2=strtolower($v2);}
      if(!isset($arr2[$v2])){
          $arr2[$v2]=1;
      }else{
           $arr2[$v2]++;
           }
    }
    }
    return $arr2;
}
```

Em **$ar1[]** troque pelos seus arrays